# Remove Vue js routing url hashtag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

my `main.js` looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from './router'
import routes from './router/index.js'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
routes,
mode: 'history'
})
new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
render: h => h(App)
})
```

Im trying to remove the hashtag from the url...
Im using Webpack for the development and as you can see im importing the routes file.
I'm seeing this error everytime

> "Uncaught TypeError: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1router__.a is not a
>   constructor"

Does anybody have a good doc for router?

this is the /router/index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Settings from '@/components/Settings'
import Login from '@/components/Login'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({

  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/Settings',
    name: 'Settings',
    component: Settings
  }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the import statement of the VueRouter should be

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

**EDIT**

You are setting up the VueRouter in `./router/index.js` file itsels , so add the `mode:'history'` property there itself

**./router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Settings from '@/components/Settings'
import Login from '@/components/Login'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/Settings',
    name: 'Settings',
    component: Settings
  }
  ]
})
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {router} from './router/index.js'


new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: I've change it on the main.js file and now have another different error:
--Uncaught TypeError: routes.forEach is not a function--

Comment: @user3380738 can you show your `'./router/index.js'` file

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks! @VamsiKrishna